# jQuery not firing event after <select> option selected on tablet

Tags: jquery, select, tablet

I have a simple  list whose id is bound to a jQuery ‘click’ event. When the user selects a quantity, the form calculates the total price and displays it in an adjacent  field:

```
<select id="qty" name="blah" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="">
    <option value="0" selected="">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

```js
$("#qty").click(function() {
    /* use qty and unit price to get and display  total price */
    $("#price").val(parseFloat($("#qty").val() * unit_price).toFixed(2));
});
```

Very simple and works fine on a PC but fails not just on iPads (which I know have hover vs click oddities) but also on Android, in spite of the 
style="cursor:pointer" onclick=""    (which should be overkill!).

The function IS being invoked on the click which displays the options drop-down list, but on tablets is NOT then invoked when the qty is selected from the list (price is displayed as 0.00). But if the option is clicked again selecting the same qty, the price is displayed correctly. Even stranger, if the qty is changed on a second or subsequent click, the price displayed is always ‘one click behind’.

For example:
Say the unit price is 50; if I firstly select a qty of 1, the price displayed is 0.00. If I select 1 again, the price displayed is 50.00. If I then select a qty of 2, the price displayed is still 50.00. But if I now select a qty of 3, the price displayed is 100.00. Etc.

The problem seems not to be the usual hover vs click problem but something to do with how jQuery on tablets fires events after an option from a dropdown list is selected.

DAK what am I doing wrong pls?

Comment: You should be using the `change` event on a select

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `change` instead on `onClick`:

```
$("#qty").change(function() {
    /* use qty and unit price to get and display  total price */
    $("#price").val(parseFloat($("#qty").val() * unit_price).toFixed(2));
});
```

Comment: It is not `onChange()` but `change()` in JQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @adeneo, you should change your function to this:

```
$("#qty").change(function() {
    /* use qty and unit price to get and display  total price */
    $("#price").val(parseFloat($("#qty").val() * unit_price).toFixed(2));
});
```